# gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: python, c++, node.js, msbuild

When I run `npm install`, I face the following error. I am not able to find the problem.

I need some help in finding this issue.

```
d:\testing\node-sample-module\node_modules\ffi\node_modules\ref\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_pre_12_inl.h(112): error C2668: 'v8::FunctionTemplate::New' :  ambiguous call to overloaded function [d:\TESTING\node-sample-module\node_modules \ffi\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
C:\Users\SELVA\.nw-gyp\0.8.5\deps\v8\include\v8.h(3344): could be 'v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::FunctionCallback,v8::Handle<v8::Value>,v8::Handle<v8::Signature>,int)'
C:\Users\SELVA\.nw-gyp\0.8.5\deps\v8\include\v8.h(3343): or v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::InvocationCallback,v8::Handle<v8::Value>,v8::Handle<v8::Signature>,int)' while trying to match the argument list '(int, v8::Local<v8::Value>,    v8::Local<v8::Signature>)'

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Users\SELVA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nw-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Users\\SELVA\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\nw-gyp\\bin\\nw-gyp.js" "clean" "configure" "--target=0.8.5" "build" "--arch=ia32"
gyp ERR! cwd d:\TESTING\node-sample-module\node_modules\ffi\node_modules\ref
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! nw-gyp -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! not ok
```

FYI, I am using windows 7 machine.

Also, have the following installed:

- Visual C++ Redistributable 2013 (32 bit)
- Python 2.7.3 (env variable set to path/python.exe)
- Visual studio Express 2013
- .Net framework 4.5 SDK

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 24):

**Update:**

A new package will do all of this for us now.

Make sure you have the sufficient permissions by running:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

then run:

`npm install -g windows-build-tools`

wait for it to install and then run:

`window-build-tools`

and everything should be in its finest order.

---

**Old answer:**

I just went through some of the same issues as you. I spun up a fresh installation of Windows 8.1 in Hyper-V, went through the installation process and jotted things down a long the way. It seems that you have all the necessary tools installed.

I think the only think you might be missing (not being entirely sure though) could be setting the `msvs_version`-flag when running `npm install` - so try seeing if this helps:

```
npm install --msvs_version=2013
```

---

Now that I've done all these notes I might as well put them here, so people that experience the same kind of problems might find some help.

My recipe on a freshly installed machine:

1) **Install Node.js**

2) **Install git**

- **CLI commands should be executed with administrator rights**
- Select "Use Git and optional Unix tools from the Windows Command Prompt

  - [image: git-add-to-path]

3) **Upgrade npm to npm 3.x.x** (optional step)

Even though you've just installed Node.js it doesn't necessarily mean you have npm in version 3.

- **CLI commands should be executed with administrator rights**
- Run `npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade` in the command line interface.
- Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force` in the command line interface
- Run `npm-windows-upgrade` in the command line interface
- Select the newest version and let it install
- When it finishes the install run `npm --version` and make sure it responds with something like `3.x.x`

4) **Install Python 2.7.x**

- Go to https://www.python.org/downloads
- Click the button to download Python 2.7.x
- Run the installer.
- Select `Install for all users` - click next.
- Select to install in `C:\Python27` - click next

  - [image: python-location]
- Be sure to select `Will be installed on local hard drive` in `Add python.exe to Path` - click next

  - [image: python-add-to-path-01]
  - [image: python-add-to-path-02]
  - [image: python-add-to-path-03]
- Finish up the installation

5) **Install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop with Update 4**

Even if you have another version of Visual Studio installed on your system do install this as well.

- Go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44914
- Select `English` or some other available language and click `Download`
- Check `wdexpress_full.exe` and click "Next"
- Run the file downloaded. Begin the installation.
- If you're unable to start the installation, it means you already have the necessary tools for this step. Abort the installation.

Now run `npm install --msvs_version=2013` and you should be able to reach the end without node-gyp throwing errors.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was because I was running node 14. Try downdrading your node version to node 12. Its pretty easy to do if you are using NVM

Answer (score 1):

For me on Windows 10 and Node 13, I had to uninstall Visual Studio and Build Tools, and uninstall Node 13. Then, I deleted npm and npm-cache from Roaming, before reinstalling Node 11.6 and choosing to install Chocolately. It worked for me thereafter.